# How to make textarea to fill div block?

Tags: css, textarea, width

Check out how far have I got it here: [*link was removed*]
How can I make the textarea above the green button to fill the div block? 
I mean, how to make the textarea exactly the same width as the comment block?

Comment: Try giving it a `width: 100%`

Comment: If it would be that simple.
Anyway, added. Check the link. :P

Comment: `width: 100%` causes it to overflow. You could just set the width to 488px, which is the width of your other boxes. I've not checked to see why it overflows though - fixing that might be a better solution.

Comment: This is tricky. It overflows because of the Box Model and `padding`. Forcing a `display: block` on it doesn't work either, neither does `width: auto` (which should force a block level element into taking up the full width without overflowing). Good question - I would usually end up using pixel widths, but would be interested to see a solution.

Comment: Pekka, yep it's tricky. I'll rather keep trying as I don't like using pixel width. ;D

Comment: The link in the question doesn't work, could you post what CSS definitions you used to eventually achieve your goal? Or what took you closest if it wasn't fully achieved... I'm trying to figure this out myself.

Comment: @stalemate, sorry for the link, it was long ago it appears it has been removed and I can't find the relevant issue and solution anymore. :/

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Please refer to this article which implements the CSS3 box-sizing property
http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

A quick solution for this is to set

```
textarea {
     width: 100%;
     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
     box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
```

And here is a working example which implements the box-sizing property
http://css-tricks.com/examples/BoxSizing/

Using widths like 99% or somewhat lesser to adjust within the container div, has already been discouraged.

Comment: Nice and clean solution, Thanks! BUT "Support IE8+: box-sizing"... Mind that I wrote the above answer two years ago when IE8 was the latest version. And even now you might still have a lot of users running XP+IE6 depending on your customers.

Comment: @Vinz, its true with your concern.
However, I believe "Using a old browser is to suffer on your own". If IE doesn't support, then its IE's problem, why should it be our problem :) 

-

Comment: @Vinz, I am not sure on how you feel about it, but "Bootstrap" from twitter is a awesome platform to start on interface for the modern days, and it would be better if we try to import features from these heavily optimized platforms.

Comment: Also note you usually want to use `min-width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;` so that it adjusts as you resize the window, but doesn't remain a larger or smaller size than the width of your window.

Having `width: 100%;` only sets the textarea to 100% initially, but users resizing it can ruin the layout and sizing of the textbox, which I assume most people want to prevent most of the time.

Answer (score 6):

Dimensioning textareas in percents has somehow never worked properly, I had the same problem years ago and ended up using width: 99%....

I suggest you use a `div` around the textarea to draw the rounded border and remove the border on the textarea itself. This way the width of the textarea doesn't need to be exact, you could use 98% or 99%.

Comment: Oh, well - check the link.
It worked out pretty good, but still I'm wondering maybe someone knows a way how to make dimensioning textareas in percents properly in my case?